# add multiple fragment to cheesesquare demo

Tags: android-fragments, android-tablayout, android-coordinatorlayout, android-appbarlayout

I am using an open source project(https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare) to develop my own application.

what I want is:

1.In the Home Fragment, there is a tablayout below to the toobar,and when the recycelview scroll, the Toolbar can hide, but the  FloatingActionButton always stay;
[image]

[image]
2. In the Message Frgment, the is no Tab and on FloatingActionButton, only a simple blank Fragment with a Toolbar.
[image]

I try to do this in MainActivity:

```
private void setupDrawerContent(NavigationView navigationView) {
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(
                new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                menuItem.setChecked(true);


                FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                Fragment fragment = null;

                int id = menuItem.getItemId();

                if (id == R.id.nav_home) {

                    fragment = new HomeFragment();
                } else if (id == R.id.nav_message) {

                    fragment = new MessageFragment();
                } else if (id == R.id.nav_friends) {

                    fragment = new FriendsFragment();
                } else if (id == R.id.nav_discussion) {

                    fragment = new DiscussionFragment();
                }

                ft.replace(R.id.viewpager, fragment);
                ft.commit();

                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
```

but this not work, because the tablayout stay both in HomeFragment and MessageFragment.

When I try to do change the tablayout to the layout xml of HomeFragment, I also meet some problem because the below code should write in MainActivity

```
tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

I feel puzzled, what should I do to achieve my goals?

Answer (score 0):

I try to solve the problem like [this](https://github.com/smartshuai/MaterialDesignNavTabDemo), implement the basic functions.